# Failed building react native app with EAS build

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I have made a react native app with the help of expo framework. But when I try building, it failed many times

This is my enviroment

```
  EAS CLI 3.15.0 environment info:                                                       
    System:                                                                              
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045                                                          
    Binaries:                                                                            
      Node: 17.9.0 - D:\Node\node.EXE                                                    
      npm: 8.5.5 - D:\Node\npm.CMD                                                       
    Utilities:                                                                           
      Git: 2.41.0.                                                                       
    npmPackages:                                                                         
      expo: ^47.0.0 => 47.0.14                                                           
      react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0                                                            
      react-native: 0.70.8 => 0.70.8                                                     
    Project workflow: managed
```

This is error log.

```
1278 439 actionable tasks: 439 executed
1279 FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1280 1: Task failed with an exception.
1281-----------
1282* What went wrong:
1283 Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:prepareBoost'.
1284 > Could not read /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/build/downloads/boost_1_76_0.tar.gz.
1285   > Not in GZIP format
1286 * Try:
1287 > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
1288 > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1289 > Run with --scan to get full insights.
1290 ==============================================================================
1291 2: Task failed with an exception.
1292 -----------
1293 * What went wrong:
1294 java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
1295 * Try:
1296 > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
1297 > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1298 > Run with --scan to get full insights.
1299 ==============================================================================
```

I tried rebuilding three times and nothing happen. It still failed

Answer (score 0):

only need to uninstall your @react-native-community/cli-platform-android package and reinstall it. It work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary solution for this until the actual problem will be fixed. Also available on the following [GitHub page](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19596)

1. Go to node_modules > expo-modules-core > android > build.gradle
2. Look for the following link `https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/${BOOST_VERSION.replace("_", ".")}/source/boost_${BOOST_VERSION}.tar.gz`
3. Change it into this link `https://archives.boost.io/release/${BOOST_VERSION.replace("_", ".")}/source/boost_${BOOST_VERSION}.tar.gz`
4. Run `npx patch-package expo-modules-core`

I could make local builds using `npx expo run:android` from this point. If the issue keeps happening, to the exact same thing at the following file.

node_modules > react-native > ReactAndroid > build.gradle

**Explanation**

The first error is happening because the file from the link that should be downloaded is offline and can not be downloaded resulting in an error. The new link is a mirror site containing the same files which you can use.

Note: that this is a solution to the first error.

Answer (score 0):

Install this package,

```
npx expo install expo-modules-core
```

This solved my problem.